# jQuery UI Autocomplete: How to storage the items not only the values?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

this is my code. You can also watch [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fU8hn/) for a live demo.

```
$(function()
{
    var source = [{id:1, value: "One"},
                 {id:2, value: "Two"},
                 {id:3, value: "Three"},
                 {id:4, value: "Four"}];

    $("input").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response)
        {
            var term = request.term.split(/,\s*/).pop();

            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(source, term));
        },
        select: function(e, ui)
        {
            var terms = this.value.split(/,\s*/);

            terms.pop();
            terms.push(ui.item.value, "");

            this.value = terms.join(", ");

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I have implemented a simple multiselect. My problem is, that I don't only need the values from the original datasource, but also their IDs. How can this be done? How can I get all items I have selected in their entirety after I'm done with the autocomplete field?

Comment: you can use ui.item.id in your select function?

Comment: Yes, but I need all items that are currently selected (= represent with their values in the textbox).

Comment: each time you select an item the select function is called, then just add the selected item to an array or json object ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fU8hn/4/) link this will you to represent the selected value and it id in autocomplete.

```
terms.push(ui.item.id+"="+ui.item.value, "");
```

i hope this will help you more.

**EDIT:** i have updated this fiddle.

Comment: Thx for your help but this isn't what I want. I want a method or property that will return me all items which are currently selected with the autocomplete (= they are represented with their values in the textbox).

Comment: I have updated my fiddle link above. Take a look at that link. I hope this will help you.

Comment: This seems to be at least a good starting point. You have to keep track of the items in a separate storage. Thank you.